# How can I divide a continuous RXJava stream on the fly based on the elements in the stream?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

The simplest example would be a stream of strings like this:

```java
["3", "a", "b", "c", "1", "a", "2", "a", "b"]
```

The ones that are numbers describe how many more elements should it's group contain.

Very important that the stream is continuous so we cant just wait for the next number to split the stream.

As far as I know there is no built in functionality for this in RXJava2

```java
var flowable = Flowable.concat(Flowable.fromArray("3", "a", "b", "c", "1", "a", "2", "a", "b"), Flowable.never());

flowable/*Something here*/.blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
```

And the expected output would be:

```
[3, a, b, c]
[1, a]
[2, a, b]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've later found akarnokd's [RxJava2Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions) package. Using that, I was able to construct this, which does what I want:

```java
var flowable = Flowable.concat(Flowable.fromArray("3", "a", "b", "c", "1", "a", "2", "a", "b"), Flowable.never());
flowable.compose(FlowableTransformers.bufferUntil(new Predicate<>() {
    private int remaining = 0;
    @Override
    public boolean test(String next) {
        if(next.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)) {
            remaining = Integer.parseInt(next);
        }
        return --remaining < 0;
    }
})).blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: A word of caution, the Flowable you have constructed is not reusable. To be reusable the `remaining` field needs to be by-subscription. The `defer` operator gives you what you need: `Flowable.defer(() -> flowable.compose(...))`